# Unit testing Linear Search method

Tags: java, unit-testing

Im trying to learn some unit testing for more complicated methods. I have a linear search method that searches an array and returns another array that contains the indexes of the "target" if found. How would I go about writing a test for this method?  here is the method below.

```
public static <T extends Comparable> int[] linearSearch3 (T[] data, T 
       target)

   int count = 0;
   int index = 0;
   int[] indices = new int[data.length];


   for (int i = 0; i < data.length;i++){
       if (data[i] == null) break;
       if (data[i].compareTo(target) == 0){ 
           indices[count] = i;
           count++;
       }
    }
    Arrays.copyOf(indices, count);
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(indices,count);

    if(count != 0){
     return copy;
    }
    else 
        return null;
```

Here is what i have so far in my test method. The two arrays are fields of my test class. intArray being the array i'm searching. and newArray being the array i want to return? however, i am not sure if i'm even going about doing this correctly.  Im getting an incompatible types error on the second line. "no instances of type variables T exist so that int[] conforms to Integer where T is a type-variable".

```
private final Integer[] intArray = {2, 5, 6, 8, 12, 17, 3, 45, 29, 88, 76, 54, 
1, 12, 5, 41, 12, 99};

private final Integer[] newArray = {2};

     @Test
     public <T extends Comparable> void testLinearSearch3() {

    System.out.println("Testing LinearSearch3");
    Integer result = Searching.linearSearch3(intArray,(Integer)2);
```

any help would be appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If newArray is supposed to contain indices of 2, I think it should be {0} instead of {2}

The returned value would also be an int[], then you can call assertEquals() to compare the the returned array and newArray

```
int[] result = Searching.linearSearch3(intArray,(Integer)2);
for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
    assertEquals(result[i], (int)newArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend adding a length assertion before the loop, and feed assertEquals both results[i] and newArray[i], so they can use the Objects#equal interface

Answer (score 0):

Your `testLinearSearch3()` method does not depend on the T type parameter, so the `<T extends Comparable>` declaration is not necessary there.  You're explicitly using the `Integer` type in the body of the test method and the array, which fulfills the type parameter requirement on the definition of the `linearSearch3(...)` method